# AngularJS input validation

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I have this html

```
<ons-input id="username" modifier="underbar" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" float ng-model="page.username" ></ons-input>

<ons-input id="password" modifier="underbar" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" float ng-model="page.password" ></ons-input>
<img ng-click="login()" class="boton-login" src="img/boton_acceder.png"></img>
```

my login function looks like this.

```
$scope.login = function(){
    if ($scope.page.username.length==0 || typeof $scope.page.username =="undefined"){
       ons.notification.alert("Error");
 }else{
      //More code.
   }
}
```

I am getting error: `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`, i have tried with angularjs classes of `$dirty`, and `$error`, but still getting the same problem, so if anybody knows how to know if my input is empty when I click on the button, help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you didn't defined `page`.

I recommend you to do this way:

```
app.controller('demoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.page = { username: new String() };

    $scope.login = function () {
        if ($scope.page.username !== undefined)
            if ($scope.page.username.length === 0)
                console.log('error');
            else
                console.log('ok');

    }
});
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3HqwNGgyWgX0UZ7kCCD5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.page` is undefined when `$scope.page.username` is being evaluated. Should work if you check to see if `$scope.page` is defined at that point:

```
$scope.login = function(){
    if ($scope.page.username.length==0){
       ons.notification.alert("Error");
 }else{
      //More code.
   }
}
```

Also if you want the `$scope.page` object to always exist (from the beginning) you should define `$scope.page = { username: '' }` in your controller.

Comment: You have to define `username` too, else length will be length of undefined thing

Comment: @JaimeCuellar You should try to add username to $scope.page. Works for me on the example I threw together. Please see my modified code.